# There was an error compiling the header file

Tags: c, clion

#### 1.Real result

In the CLion compiler, when I tried to compile, I got the following error:

The following are some warnings from the errors.

```c
f:/my_app/gcc-arm/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/OLED.elf.dir/Core/Src/gpio.c.obj:F:\STM32\Oled\Core\Inc/oled_animation.h:45: multiple definition of `sin_table'; CMakeFiles/OLED.elf.dir/Core/Src/dma.c.obj:F:\STM32\Oled\Core\Inc/oled_animation.h:45: first defined here
f:/my_app/gcc-arm/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/OLED.elf.dir/Core/Src/main.c.obj:F:\STM32\Oled\Core\Inc/oled_animation.h:45: multiple definition of `sin_table'; CMakeFiles/OLED.elf.dir/Core/Src/dma.c.obj:F:\STM32\Oled\Core\Inc/oled_animation.h:45: first defined here
```

The errors appear to indicate that I have multiply defined some variables, but I have only declared these variables in the `oled_animation.h` file.

#### 2. Cause analysis

In the first header file `oled_animation.h`, I included the following code:

```c
#include "oled.h"
```

In the second header file `oled_ui.h`, I included the following code:

```c
#include "oled.h"
#include "oled_animation.h"
```

So,I think it might be because the two header files, `oled_ui.h` and `oled_animation.h`, are conflicting.

The result of my search using CLion's find function is as follows. This variable is found in the error message, so I searched for it.

When I simply commented out the `oled_animation.h` file, CLion no longer reported an error.

Even if the `oled_ui.h` file is added to the `oled_animation.h` file, it does not cause any compilation errors.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, not only copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question, also show the [mre] that causes the error.

Comment: As an educated ***guess***, you probably have mixed up the terms *declaration* and *definition*. In a header file you should only *declare* variables, and in a single source file you should *define* it. So in the header file have (for example) `extern int my_var;`. That's a *declaration*. Then in a source file do `int my_var = 123;`. That's a *definition*. In C you should only have one single definition in a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), but you can have as many declarations as you want.

Comment: CLion is not a compiler.

Comment: @Jamth Do not post information essential to your question in _comments_.  Edit the question.  Answers should only reference information in the question, so the information must be in the question.  Also posting code in comments is problematic in any case.  SO is not a discussion forum, it is a Q&A.

Comment: I suggest you just present your observation without an attempt at "cause analysis" or any speculation of the cause. If you knew the cause, you would not be asking the question.  If you include your flawed "analysis" any answer may have to address  both the problem _and_ your misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocessor inclusion is a very simple thing, all included files are recursively expanded into a single translation unit which is then presented to the compiler as a single file.

The *linker* then takes the multiple *separately compiled* object and library modules and combines them into a single executable.

The important thing to note here is that the errors you have presented are *linker errors* and not either *preprocessor* or *compiler* errors.

The mistake you have made is to place *definitive* rather than *declarative* code in a header file.  The result is that every *separately compiled* translation unit that includes a header containing `sin_table` (directly or by nested inclusion) will contain a separate definition such that the *linker* sees multiple definitions if the same symbol and cannot resolve them.

The solution is to *define* `sin_table` in *exactly* one translation unit, but *declare* it in a (preferably) *single* header file.

So for example you might have:

```c
// sin_table.c
#include "sin_table.h"

const double sin_table[] = { ...  } ; // definition
```

```c
// sin_table.h
#pragma once

extern const double sin_table[] ;  // declaration
```

Then any translation unit, you can freely include sin_table.h to see a *single declaration* and the linker will resolve all references to the *single definition* in the compiled object generated from sin_table.c.